# Set keyboard combination for .lnk shortcut

Tags: vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, sendkeys, lnk

I am trying to set keyboard combination for a `.lnk` shortcut using vbs. For some reason the 'shortcut key' section will not accept emulated letter key presses. All I get is `pause` key. For  some reason `Enter` key as well as `Tab`, `Esc` work, meaning I can switch to next line or close shortcut properties altogether. Please adivise.

[image]

This is the VBS script I am using.

```
set WshSHell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{1}"                              *for simplicity I named the shortcut "1"*                                    
WshShell.SendKeys "+{F10}"                           *emulates righ-click*
WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"                             *select 'Properties'*
WshShell.Sendkeys"{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 500                                    *wait fo window to pop-up*
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}"                          *switch to 'shortcut key' line*
WshShell.SendKeys "{G}"                              *error*
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: The answer is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use Sendkeys to do this. You can actually edit the properties of the shortcut, including the Hotkey in code.

From the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh)

```
WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\Sample.lnk")
oMyShortcut.WindowStyle = 3 &&Maximized 7=Minimized 4=Normal
oMyShortcut.IconLocation = "C:\myicon.ico"
OMyShortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\notepad.exe"
oMyShortCut.Hotkey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
oMyShortCut.Save
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some tweaking and it now suits my needs. Most of all I had to place 'set' at the begining of WshShell and first oMyDesktop lines and remove what seems to be a comment on 'WindiwStyle' line.  Please see below.

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
set oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut("PATH\test.lnk")
oMyShortcut.WindowStyle = 4
oMyShortcut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,63"
OMyShortcut.TargetPath = "PATH\test.bat"
oMyShortCut.Hotkey = "ALT+CTRL+K"
oMyShortCut.Save
```